# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' can be called without a narrowing conversion

Tags: vb.net, overloading, resolution, strict

So, i'm attempting to follow [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308063) guide to populate a treeview from XML Data in Visual Basic, but it throws the error:

> "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' can be
>   called without a narrowing conversion:
>       'Public Overridable ReadOnly Default Property Item(key As String) As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode': Argument matching parameter 'key'
>   narrows from 'Long' to 'String'.
>       'Public Overridable Default Property Item(index As Integer) As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode': Argument matching parameter 'index'
>   narrows from 'Long' to 'Integer'."

After some searching, I was told that setting Option Strict to "Off" would solve the error, but it has done no such thing. Does anyone have a solution to this error?

Here is the code in question:

```
 If inXmlNode.HasChildNodes() Then
     nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes
     For i = 0 To nodeList.Count - 1
        xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes(i)
        inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xNode.Name))
        tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes(i)
        AddNode(xNode, tNode) //The code that throws the error.
     Next
  Else
     ' Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
     ' type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
     inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim
  End If
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant section of your code and indicate which statement get the error. It appears you are using a `Long` to get a specific item and the `Item` method expects an `Integer` or a `String`. Most likely you should just use an `Integer` instead of a `Long`.

Comment: My code is the exact same as what I linked above, but the code it errors on is this code in particular.
'AddNode(xNode, tNode)'

Comment: The statement you quote is calling to the AddNode method which requires two TreeNode objects as its arguments (which you have provided). That's hard to understand how the compiler can think you are provide a `Long` when either an `Integer` or a `String` are required. Are you sure it isn't the previous statement that gets the error?

Comment: I'm quite sure, [here's](http://i.imgur.com/lpkPieu.png?1) a picture of Visual Studio too.

Comment: Look at the picture again, the statement that is flagged is indeed the previos one `tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes(i)`. It is failing to compile for the reason given; it is expecting `i` to be either an `Integer` or a `String`. You can fix this by declaring `i` as an `Integer`, although I don't know of there is some other reason for declaring it as `Long.

Answer (score 0):

Define i as an Integer instead of Long. It should match the overload then.

```
 Private Sub AddNode(ByRef inXmlNode As XmlNode, ByRef inTreeNode As TreeNode)
      Dim xNode As XmlNode
      Dim tNode As TreeNode
      Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
      Dim i As Integer


    If inXmlNode.HasChildNodes() Then
         nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes
         For i = 0 To nodeList.Count - 1
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes(i)
            inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xNode.Name))
            tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes(i)
            AddNode(xNode, tNode) //The code that throws the error.
         Next
      Else
         ' Here you need to pull the data from the XmlNode based on the
         ' type of node, whether attribute values are required, and so forth.
         inTreeNode.Text = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim
      End If
```